# Conditional if statement

Tags: php, magento

I would like to add a list of categories to my conditional statement, how should I add multiple categories id ?
Using like 123,124,125 or 123 || 124

I have a big list of categories so I am looking for the cleanest way to achieve that

thanks

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getId();
    }

?>

  <?php if($cat->getId()==123): ?>
    <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('myblockid')->toHtml();?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: use `in_array()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array - 'in\_object' equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041533/in-array-in-object-equivalent)

Comment: @RJParikh if you mark it as duplicate, do this properly. It's topic about searching objects, not arrays. `in_array` is provided there as example how it should works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `in_array` PHP function:

```
<?php if(in_array($cat->getId(), [123, 124, 125])): ?>
```

Comment: actually it's not working for me, please check my full code I just added before. I get a blank page with "in_array"

Comment: But where you hold categories which should met criteria in `if` statement?

Comment: I want to manually add a bunch of category ids, if a product belongs to that category, the block is displayed

Comment: my initial code works, but I need to add more category ids. When I use array stops working.

Comment: Well, i see you closed `}` of your `foreach` loop before `if` statement. If you want to loop over it, change placement of `}` to after your `if` statement.

Comment: Funny thing - i did syntax error here, and all answers were copied with this syntax error ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function

```
<?php
   if(in_array($cat->getId(), $your_array){
      $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('myblockid')->toHtml();
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array()` : This Checks if a value exists in an array or not.Return true if exist.

```
<?php
    if(in_array($cat->getId(), $categories ):
        echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('myblockid')->toHtml();
    endif;
?>
```